# Sharing websockets object between tornado processes

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, multiprocessor

I start the tornado server with multiple processes:

```
   server.bind(8000)
   server.start(0)
```

Assuming I have a 4 processor system this should create 4 processes. For any client that connects I start a websocket (WS) connection. I want to be able to access websocket objects between processes because I may want to broadcast a message between client A on process 1 to client B on process 2. I have a mongo server and the solution i thought of was to pickle the WS for client 1 store it in mongo then get process 2 to retrieve this and unpickle then use the WS. However I don't believe picked objects can be shared between processes.

Can someone suggest the best way to share WS between tornado processes on a multi process system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live connections cannot be pickled and stored in a database. Instead, each connection is owned by the process that first accepted it, and instead of passing connections around, you pass messages to the server that is handling a particular client.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I have thought about it a bit more and passing WS around probably isn't a good idea. I've been looking at the multiprocessing.Manager() library however it's getting quite complicated and I'm not sure it's compatible with tornado. Another way i was thinking was to use mongo so that each process has its own queue once items are placed on the queue it would signal to the other processes that work much be done. Then use PeriodicCallback() to service the items... What other options do I have between communicating between processes?

Comment: There are many options for inter-process communication, but Redis seems to be the most popular choice for this kind of task.

Comment: ok thanks i actually started out with Redis and moved to mongo because i didn't like any of the async library support. Where as mongo had Motor which had much better documentation.